# Why does Sequel Pro show a different result for a table's key values than MySQL on the command line?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, primary-key, sequelpro

This is the structure of a particular table in Sequel Pro:

[image: Sequel Pro Table]

This is that same table structure as viewed on the command line:

[image: MySQL Command Line]

Here is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE field_data_field_checklist_status`:

```
| field_data_field_checklist_status | 
CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_checklist_status` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_checklist_status_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_checklist_status_value` (`field_checklist_status_value`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 7 (field_checklist_status)' |
```

I am fairly confident that the MySQL command line table structure is the accurate one. This is a Drupal field table.

**Does anyone know why there would be a discrepancy?**

Comment: It's probably not set up to handle your compound PRIMARY key. Can you show us the table schema as `SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs for both?

Comment: Thanks. I've included that output in my edited question.

Comment: I see the same thing when I run your schema. I'd report it as a bug to Sequel Pro, with the table schema included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that there's both a primary key that has `entity_type` as a column, and a multiple key that has it as a column? Then the value of `Key` would be ambiguous, and it would explain the inconsistency.

The best way to inspect keys in MySQL is to run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE field_data_field_checklist_status;
```

It will show you the actual keys, with the order of columns within them.

Comment: Good shout, entity_type has its own index as well as being part of the compound key. Delta is also part of the key but isn't indexed separately, and is showing as `PRI`, so this is almost certainly just how Sequel Pro deals with columns that are in multiple indexes